# scrolling to a location on div Id using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to navigate to a div based on it's after capturing the Id from Url.

The url is like below first time when user is navigated to this page

```
http://localhost:6447/products/all-products#productId2
```

Here is #productId2 is div id in the page to which i need to scroll on page load

I am displaying products in listview with paging

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id='#productId<%#Eval("PId")%>'>
                            <a class="ProdcutText">
                                <%#Eval("PName")%></a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="PriceText">
                            -<a class="PPrice"><%#Eval("Price")%></a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="PDesc">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PrdocutDescription")%>'> </asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

and in content page i tried below but doesn't seem to work.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterHeadContentHolder" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#productId6").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

What is wrong? and after paging the url changes to and i get error of undefined and null error.

```
http://localhost:6447/products/all-products?list=1
```

Comment: This is a server issue, ASP adds the querystring for paging, but doesn't add the location hash, so it gone!

Comment: @adeneo: Yes i know. it gone so how to handle this situation when it is null.

Answer (score 0):

clearly your **html should be generate** like below:

```
<div id="productId2">
   Proiduct details
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It just written # also in the Id.Can you guide me how to get the value from url and apply to pass the value to jquery to scroll?

Comment: I get error 'JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference' when i navigate using paging as #productId is not available in the next page. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Javascript code:

```
    var $target = $( location.hash);
    var pos = Math.max( 0, $target.offset().top);
    var $view = browser.indexOf('WebKit') < 0 ? $('html') : $(document.body);
    $view.animate({'scrollTop': pos});
```

The first line gets the productId from the URL, like #productId2
Then it finds the element with that id, # being the jQuery selector for ID.
The second line calculates the position of that element down the page (the scroll amount).
The third line decides what is to be scrolled, the HTML (for Chrome & Safari) or the BODY.
The last line does the smooth scrolling.

Comment: Thanks. But few times i got error 'JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference'. as well as it jumps to location and it doesn't do animation.

Comment: To avoid the error just add an if( $target.length){ after the first line and close it with } after the last one.

Answer (score 0):

**please try below code when you file name suppose as test.html then you type url 
test.html#div1 it will scroll to div 1
test.html#div2 it will scroll to div 2**

```
<html>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div1">div</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div2">Div start</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that html code only. No need  for _js_ or any other stuff   .

Comment: sorry. but i didn't understand. and how to solve 'JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference' error?

Comment: here no need of javascript you can do by only pure html .